# Put array variables in order

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my array:

```
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
    (
        [2] => x
        [4] => y
        [6] => z
    )
```

I'm looking for a way to put my `[c]` array variables in "order". Making my array, look like this:

```
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
(
        [1] => x
        [2] => y
        [3] => z
)
```

Is there a way to do it without creating a new function by myself?

Comment: Fortunately PHP provides a lot of [sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), you don't have to write another one. Try `sort($a['c'])` (assuming your array is stored in the `$a` variable).

Comment: The values in `$a['c']` are already in order. Is it important to have their keys starting with `1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try with reassigning `c` value:

```
$data['c'] = array_values($data['c']);
```

It will reindex your `c` array, but the indexes will start with `0`. If you really want to start with `0`, try:

```
$data['c'] = array_combine(range(1, count($data['c'])), array_values($data['c']))
```

Comment: Awesome!! That's it, thanks a lot! :) I'll mark this as  an answer asap

Comment: And also, I didn't mean to have them start from 1, my mistake. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately PHP provides a lot of functions for [array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), you don't have to write another one.

Try `sort($a['c'])` (assuming your array is stored in the $a variable).

```
$a = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
    'c' => array(
        '1' => 'x',
        '2' => 'y',
        '3' => 'z',
    ),
);

sort($a['c']);
print_r($a);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

If you don't need to sort the content of `$a['c']` and only want to re-index it (let it have numeric consecutive keys starting with `0`) then [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is all it needs:

```
$a['c'] = array_values($a['c']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how many arrays needs to be sorted, try this:

```
$testarr = ['a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => ['x', 'y', 'z']];

foreach ($testarr as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item)) { $arr[$key] = array_values($item); }
    // if (is_array($item)) { $arr[$key] = asort($item); } // use asort() if you want to keep subarray keys
}
```